# Python requests GET continuous HTML stream unknown size

Tags: python-3.x, events, get, streaming, python-requests

I am using Python3 and requests to connect to an embedded device. The embedded device produces an HTML data stream. I can connect successfully and receive the data. It comes through sporadically as events are generated on the embedded device. There is no known content size and no specific end to the stream. Events can produce 'blocks' of data with varying lengths of text, and at irregular intervals.

When using the following code I can see the data as it comes through:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
url='http://url goes here'
usr='username'
pwd='password'
params={'param1':'value'}
r=requests.get(url,params=params,auth=HTTPDigestAuth(usr,pwd),stream=True)
for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
    print(chunk)
```

Sorry if I missed some little details in the code example above but I think the intent is clear enough.

The next step I am trying to put in place is to handle the 'blocks' of data as they arrive (event driven) and be able to parse the body of the returned HTML (dont need the headers).

Can anyone suggest a way that I can handle the situation?

Cheers and thanks in advance

The Frog